# Creating a VBA macro that creates a new consolidated workbook from columns of another excel data-set

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create script to a macro that will copy certain columns in a large data-set in excel and create a new excel workbook of those columns in respective order -- Only the values to be copied over and not the formulas. This is what I have so far after using the Macro recorder:

```
Sub Compfinder()
'
' Compfinder Macro
'

'
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
Columns("Q:Q").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
Columns("A:A").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Geo Location"
Windows("CompFinder Tool_Protected_final_11.25.13.xlsm").Activate
Columns("K:K").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Book1").Activate
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
    , SkipBlanks:=False, transpose:=False
Windows("CompFinder Tool_Protected_final_11.25.13.xlsm").Activate
Windows("Book1").Activate
Windows("CompFinder Tool_Protected_final_11.25.13.xlsm").Activate
Columns("L:L").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Book1").Activate
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
    , SkipBlanks:=False, transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\raysharm\Documents\Compfinder columns.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
    CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

When running the macro, I end up getting a bug error for `Windows("Book1").Activate`, and I imagine I will for the other cut and pastes in the code.

Is there a way so that every time the macro is run, a brand new workbook is created with the respective desired columns to be copy and pasted? What should I put instead of "Book1"?

Thanks,
Ray

Comment: You need to create 'book1' first then you can reference it.  [Avoid Select & Active post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select) will help clean up the code.

Comment: Is there something that can be used instead of book one that allows for any new workbook to activate? ie. 'Windows("AnyNewBook").Activate? Also Book1 is not static, so why would I want to reference it? Book1 was a random name excel gave to the new workbook I opened to copy and paste the desired columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activate & Select are common problems in code.  Here is a great reference on how to avoid using them.

Here is an example of how to add a new workbook and set it to a variable so that you can easily get a reference to it later in code:

```
Sub CreateWBandCopy()
    ' Link variable to source workbook
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Set wbSource = Workbooks("book1")

    ' Copy Column L from source book
    wbSource.Sheets(1).Range("L:L").Copy

    ' Create new workbook and assign to variable
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    ' Link sheet1 to variable  -can also use name like this: Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

    ' Link Specific range to variable
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Columns("A:A")

    ' Paste source col L to new book col A
    rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Notice that the code is easy to track what is being done.  You don't have to keep track of what book or sheet or cell is currently active.

---

I'm not entirely sure about the logic of your code but here is my best guess on how to correct your references.  Note that I used a couple different techniques for referencing & setting ranges.  I wasn't trying to confuse the code but show different ways to do the same thing.

Also, I used a few active statements because I'm not sure what your source book name is.

```
Sub Compfinder()
'
' Compfinder Macro
'
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10

    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Set wsSource = wbSource.ActiveSheet

    Dim rngQ As Range
    Set rngQ = wsSource.Columns("Q:Q")

    rngQ.Copy

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add

    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Set wsNew = wbNew.Sheets(1)

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = wsNew.Columns("A:A")

    rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    wsNew.Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Geo Location"

    wsSource.Columns("K:K").Copy

    wsNew.Columns("B:B").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    wsSource.Columns("L:L").Copy

    wsNew.Columns("C:C").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    wbNew.Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\raysharm\Documents\Compfinder columns.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

With the exception of the last save (to your path) I tested that the code runs without errors.